# rails3 sqlite date comparison returning null set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, datetime, activerecord

I'm trying to select all records in a SQLite DB that have dates in the future.

```
Record.where('scheduled_date > ?', Time.now)
```

On my computer this currently returns an empty array.

However, if I use the following:

```
Record.all.map { |record| record if record.scheduled_date > Time.now }
```

I receive an array of all the Records with a future date.

Additionally, my colleague running the same Rails project on his machine was able to successfully return the expected result array using the ActiveRecord query. After recently pulling down my changes to the project, this query failed to work for him and his computer behaves like mine.

I suspect there might be an environmental mishap with SQLite (v. 1.3.6) or Rails3 (v. 3.2.3) in this Rails project and don't know where to look. Any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: It is probably a UTC issue. When you load via Ruby Record.all.map the record date is already converted to UTC. But in the where clause the Time.now is local time. What do you get if you use Time.now.iso8601 ?

Comment: Thank you peterept, the Time.now.iso8601 solved the issue!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with my sqlite3 development DB.

We were using ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone::to_s(:db) to seed the DB (calling ActiveRecord::connection.execute for speed - don't judge me for my coworkers' code :).

```
sql =<<-EOL
  INSERT INTO some_table(day)
    VALUES('#{Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day.to_s(:db)}')
EOL
SomeTable.connection.execute(sql)
```

For a query, I was passing a TimeWithZone range into an ARel in statement (to generate a sql between).

```
SomeTable.where(SomeTable.arel_table[:day].in((Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day)..(1.day.from_now)))
```

The timestamp from to_s(:db) looked something like this: `2013-10-01 04:00:00`

The timestamp in the arel-generated query looked something like this: `2013-10-01 04:00:00.000000`

Even though these should be equivalent, the DB interpreted the latter as later than the former.  It took me forever to accidentally stumble onto the fractional seconds difference, and it looks like a sqlite3 implementation bug to me (see: https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=50575).

I have a feeling this may not have been your issue (since iso8601 solved it), but hopefully this will save someone else some frustration!

Answer (score 0):

The problem stems from the fact that SQLite stores datetime values as strings. Therefore, you have to match the format exactly, taking lexicographical sort order considerations into account. With mySQL, Oracle, Postgres, etc, where the column has a distinct datatype, this is never an issue.

Another way of getting the result you expect is to do a "datetime(the_column) >= ?" or even a "datetime(the_column) >= datetime(?)", though this of course is much less efficient.